# MongoDB, aggregation over filtered elements on a nested array of a composite key elements

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

#### The problem

I have elements like these ones:

Element 1:

```
{
  "uuid" : "bc972b90-134b-0133-68be-0a81e8b09a82",
  "parent_uuid": "PARENT_UUID_1",
  "demographics" : [ 
    {
      "key" : "country_code",
      "value" : "DE"
    },
    {
      "key" : "gender",
      "value" : "female"
    }
  ]
}
```

Element 2:

```
{
  "uuid" : "bc972b90-134b-0133-68be-0a81e8b09a83",
  "parent_uuid": "PARENT_UUID_1",
  "demographics" : [ 
    {
      "key" : "country_code",
      "value" : "ES"
    },
    {
      "key" : "gender",
      "value" : "female"
    }
  ]
}
```

I would like to calculate the amount of elements per `country_code`, where the `parent_uuid == "PARENT_UUID_1"`.

As the `demographics` array is a composite key elements I don't know how to define the `group` command.

I have been checking options like [$project](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) and [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) but I don't really know how them apply to my example.

Also [this SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29879825/mongodb-group-composite-key-with-nested-fields) looks pretty similar but is not really matching my need because I need to make a double filtering:

1. Filter for the elements based on `parent_id` for the base fiinding.
2. Filter for the `demographics.key == "country_code"` for the grouping it self.

#### My approach

```
db.getCollection('test').aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "parent_uuid": {
        "$in": [
          "PARENT_UUID_1",
          "PARENT_UUID_2"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$demographics"
  },
  {
    "$group" : {
      "_id" : { 
        "country_code": "$demographics.value"
      },
      "count": { "$sum": 1 }
    }
  }  
])
```

The result:

```
{
  "result" : [ 
    {
      "_id" : {
        "country_code" : "ES"
      },
      "count" : 1.0000000000000000
    }, 
    {
      "_id" : {
        "country_code" : "female"
      },
      "count" : 4.0000000000000000
    }, 
    {
      "_id" : {
        "country_code" : "male"
      },
      "count" : 1.0000000000000000
    }, 
    {
      "_id" : {
        "country_code" : "DE"
      },
      "count" : 4.0000000000000000
    }
  ],
  "ok" : 1.0000000000000000
}
```

As expected the query is messing up the different `demographics`, I'm only interested in the `demographics.key == "country_code"`.

#### The question

How can I define this aggregation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

I didn't know that the *aggregation commands* can be concatenated so after the first `$match` I can make a `$unwind` and then another `$match`:

```
db.getCollection('test').aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "parent_uuid": {
        "$in": [
          "PARENT_UUID_1",
          "PARENT_UUID_2"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$demographics"
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "demographics.key" : "country_code"
    }
  },
  {
    "$group" : {
      "_id" : "$demographics.value",
      "count": { "$sum": 1 }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project" :{
      "_id": 0,
      "country_code": "$_id",
      "count": "$count"
    }
  }     
])
```

Result:

```
{
  "result" : [ 
    {
      "count" : 1.0000000000000000,
      "country_code" : "ES"
    }, 
    {
      "count" : 4.0000000000000000,
      "country_code" : "DE"
    }
  ],
  "ok" : 1.0000000000000000
}
```