# How to group nested fields in mongodb aggregation

Tags: python, database, mongodb, nosql, aggregation-framework

My document is a little complicated, it is like:

```
        {
            '_id': 1,
            'words':
                {
                    'a': 
                        {
                        'positions': [1,2,3],
                        'count':3,
                    },
                    'and':
                        {
                            'positions': [4, 5],
                            'count': 2,
                        }
            }
        }
```

I have many ducuments that contains very same words, I want aggregate all the fields in `words`. To give it me like:

```
                {
                    'a': 5 #a's sum count

                    'and': 6 #and's sum count
                }
```

I read this article, [MongoDB - group composite key with nested fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29879825/mongodb-group-composite-key-with-nested-fields), but unluckily, the structure is different, what they do is group the array field, not the nested field.

Any advice? Hope your answer and help, thanks in advance.

Comment: or do I have to get the result by looping in python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try following aggregation:

```
db.col.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            wordsAsKeyValuePairs: {
                $objectToArray: "$words"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$wordsAsKeyValuePairs"
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$wordsAsKeyValuePairs.k",
            count: { $sum: "$wordsAsKeyValuePairs.v.count"}
        }
    }
])
```

To aggregate over your fields you need to use [$objectToArray](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/index.html) to decompose object into array of key-value pairs. Then we're just [$unwinding](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/index.html) such array to be able to group by k which is single word and sum all the counts.

Comment: looks just like what I need. Thanks very much!